# Freeware EMF image editor

Tags: windows, gratis, image-editor, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a free (basic) image editor capable of reading and writing EMF ([enhanced metafile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Metafile)), besides the older WMF the only vector image format MS Office products can handle) vector image files.

It should run on Windows (XP or above).

I have tried already:

- MS Paint can read EMF (at least on Windows 7 and above), but only
  write bitmap image formats
- Inkscape renders the file with fatal errors and is therefore not an option

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=463AC00C6A94CB65!6885&authkey=!AHM7t4zp_npgi5Q&ithint=file%2cemf) is a sample EMF file produced by PowerPoint 2010 SP 2.

Comment: Must it be basic/minimal, or are "larger applications" an option as well? Background: IMHO Gimp should be capable of that as well, but might be a bit "overdone" just for that.

Comment: Where are the errors fatal? Where do the files come from if Inkscape can't read them there is probably a problem with the originating program.

Comment: As long as it is simple to use, a larger tool is ok. But Gimp is like Photoshop a bitmap image editor that can`t write EMF: http://www.gimphelp.org/formats.shtml

Comment: Inkscape doesn`t render some elements of the image. File is created by PowerPoint 2010 SP 2.

Comment: Can you post a sample file somewhere and a link.

Comment: Yes, here (not the original file, but made the same way and got the same errors in Inkscape 0.91): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=463AC00C6A94CB65!6885&authkey=!AHM7t4zp_npgi5Q&ithint=file%2cemf (open it with MS Paint or LibreOffice Draw in order to see it rendered correctly).

Answer (score 2):

The test file provided in the comments will open without failure in Inkscape 0.92, a more recent version than the referenced 0.91 failure. It also "save as" fine with 0.92 in .emf format.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/).

- LibreOffice Draw can both read from undamaged, valid, EMF & WMF files.
- It can export to either.
- Allows a reasonable basic level of drawing
- Free and Open Source
- Cross Platform

[image]

Comment: LibreOffice Draw treats imported EMF files as "immutable objects" on the canvas. Editing itself is not possible. Only resizing and other action leaving the image itself untouched are supported.

Answer (score 1):

For the reading part of EMF you could try this free viewer called **Kyktir**: https://www.kyktir.info/